# Create an extended view of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning image convolution and in order to handle the edges, I want to repeat the first and last rows/columns of the original array (at the center) like this :

```
1  1 2 3  3
1 [1 2 3] 3
4 [4 5 6] 6
7 [7 8 9] 9
7  7 8 9  9
```

(The values in the corners correspond to the diagonal elements.)

I will iterate over each pixel of the original array and use the array above to extract its 3x3 neighbors. So here is my question: is it possible to generate the view corresponding to this array so that I don't need to store a new (n+2)x(m+2) array in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this as a view, since there's no way to make the strides work. For a not-view solution, [`numpy.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) does the job. The signal-processing routines you're using might also let you specify a padding type.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I was aware of `scipy.signals.convolve2d` and its "boundary" parameter but I need to code it myself. I will use `numpy.pad` and if memory becomes a problem, I will handle the edges manually in my loop.